# My program won't read my file

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file, and print out how many of a specific word are in the file, but it is just printing "0". It was working, and I changed the contents of the file, then it broke and it won't work now.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.io.*;

public class TotalsGUI extends JFrame
{
   private BagelPanel bagels;     
   private ToppingPanel toppings; 
   private CoffeePanel coffee;    
   private GreetingPanel banner;  
   private JPanel buttonPanel;    
   private JButton calcButton;   
   private JButton exitButton;   
   private final double TAX_RATE = 0.06;
   int whiteCount = 0;
   int wheatCount = 0;

   public TotalsGUI() throws IOException
   {
      setTitle("Totals Calculator");

      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      banner = new GreetingPanel();
      bagels = new BagelPanel();

      buildButtonPanel();

      add(banner, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(bagels, BorderLayout.WEST);
      add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }

   private void buildButtonPanel()
   {
      // Create a panel for the buttons.
      buttonPanel = new JPanel();

      // Create the buttons.
      calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");

      // Register the action listeners.
      calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());

      // Add the buttons to the button panel.
      buttonPanel.add(calcButton);
   }

   private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         String fileName = "receipt.csv";
         String line = null;

         try 
         {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
               if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("White Bagel"))
               {
                  whiteCount++;
               }
               else if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("Wheat Bagel"))
               {
                  wheatCount++;
               }
            }

            bufferedReader.close();            
         }
         catch(FileNotFoundException ex) 
         {
            System.out.println(
               "Unable to open file '" + 
               fileName + "'");
         }
         catch(IOException ex) 
         {
            System.out.println(
               "Error reading file '" 
               + fileName + "'");
         }

         System.out.printf("White Bagels: %d\n", whiteCount);
         System.out.printf("Wheat Bagels: %d", wheatCount);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      new OrderCalculatorGUI();
   }
}
```

Comment: And what does the contents of the file look like?

Comment: White Bagel
Cream Cheese
Peach Jelly
Nutella
Cappuccino
Cinnamon Crunch Bagel
Blueberry Jam
Regular Coffee
Wheat Bagel
Blueberry Jam
Nutella
Diet Dr Pepper

Comment: It's in excel and all  in one column, but I can't put in a column here.

Comment: You don't specify a path to your file `String fileName = "receipt.csv";`  Are you sure you're in the correct directory?  What specific output do you get?  If it's *Unable to open file* you are most likely running this program in a different directory than your file.

Comment: Instead of line.equalsIgnoreCase("White Bagel"), try using if(line.indexOf("White Bagel") > -1)

Comment: @PrettyNovice: HJK's suggestion accounts for having extra white space before or after the word you're looking for.

Comment: @EricJ. I have the csv file in the same folder as my program, which is why I don't have a directory to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you would be having white spaces around the word.
You could do one of the follwoing.

Instead of

```
line.equalsIgnoreCase("White Bagel")
```

try using

```
if(line.indexOf("White Bagel")>-1)
```

or if you want to account for case insensitive then

```
 line.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("White Bagel")
```

I opt option 1, if I don't account for case sensitivity

Answer (score -1):

You can use java.util.Scanner class to break data in tokens from any input stream. You should visit this link for how scanner works

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html